Custom routing to VPN connection using Windows 11
I have a Win 11 PC which has an always-on VPN connection to a remote site. Some of the devices on my network do not support the installation of VPN client software, so I want to route those devices through the VPN connection established on the Win 11 PC.
I have setup routing rules on my pfSense router to direct internet-bound traffic to the Windows 11 PC's IP address as the default gateway for those select devices. I have enabled
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -Name "IPEnableRouter" -Value 1
on the Win 11 PC.

Without changing anything on the Win 11 PC, when the VPN connection is not up on the Win 11 PC the client devices can access the internet no problems, but obviously not over the VPN connection (just to double-check the traffic is definitely being routed through the Win 11 PC, for a sanity check I disconnected the network of the Win 11 PC and the internet on the client devices stopped working)

When I bring up the VPN connection on the Win 11 PC I can access the internet on the Win 11 PC over the VPN (a quick check of ifconfig.co shows the IP of the VPN connection) - and the client devices can still access the internet, but not over the VPN connection.

Here comes the problem. When I add a static route on the Win 11 PC to direct the client devices to use the VPN connection, such as:


route add 10.10.0.67 mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 if 4

...where 10.10.0.67 is the client device IP, and interface 4 is the index of the VPN interface, the client device can no longer access the internet or ping anything.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, it seems like something with the routing of traffic specifically to the VPN connection interface.
Any help would be appreciated.
